# Omniauth with facebook tokken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, access-token

i got a question that I' using omniauth to authenticate my user to facebook. I get their access token through gem 'omniauth-facebook' and save it in the dabatase, i want to ask that is that the access token i request always valid ? because currenly i dont face any token expire , any solution toward this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now you'll be fine, but [after July 5](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) you'll have to deal with expiring tokens. This probably means dealing with the expired token error FB sends back, and interrupting the user experience on your site to get their re-approval for a new token.

Comment: so that mean after july 5 have to improve our coding to update the token? or it will be take care by omniauth?

Comment: Omniauth only handles authentication - if you want to do more with the token beyond that, you're probably on your own.